# Unable to understand Promise then and catch behavior

Tags: javascript, promise

The actual output (when seen in Firefox console) of the below code is 
    - error1
    - error2
    - continue1
    - continue3.

```js
Promise
  .resolve()
  .then(() => Promise.reject('error1'))
  .catch(console.log)
  .then(() => console.log('continue1'))

Promise
  .resolve()
  .then(() => Promise.reject('error2'))
  .then(() => console.log('continue2'), console.log)
  .then(() => console.log('continue3'))
```

As per my understanding of promises, it should be - error1 - continue1 - error2 - continue3.

Need help in understanding the actual output

Comment: It is kind of pointless to attempt to understand a possible ordering issue between two completely independent promise chains.  When programming, you should treat their order as indeterminate (and in fact, it may vary slightly between different JS engines and Promise implementations).  If the order matters to you between the two chains, then you need to add some specific code to coordinate the actions of the two independent promise chains.

Comment: https://medium.com/@gaurav.pandvia/understanding-javascript-function-executions-tasks-event-loop-call-stack-more-part-1-5683dea1f5ec

Comment: Why do you expect that you should be `error1 - continue1 - error2 - continue3`  and not `error1 - error2 - continue1 - continue3`? You have two separate (sub) Promise chains. So their ordering can and will be interleaved. Otherwise Promises would not be really useful for to work with async code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promises that resolve/reject put a microtask in the corresponding queue. That task involves calling any `then`/`catch` callback functions. The messages in that queue are processed in sequence.

So in your example the sequence is:

- First `Promise.resolve()` is executed. The microtask queue now has 1 entry:

  - Queue = [promise #1 resolved]
- Normal execution flow continues to the second `Promise.resolve()`
- Second `Promise.resolve()` is executed. The microtask queue now has 2 entries:

  - Queue = [promise #1 resolved, promise #2 resolved]
- Normal execution flow ends -- the call stack is empty.
- The first item in the queue is extracted and processed. The `then` callback `() => Promise.reject('error1')` is executed. This creates a new, rejected promise, and so a rejection is put on the queue

  - Queue = [promise #2 resolved, promise.then #1 rejected]
- The first item in the queue is extracted and processed. The `then` callback `() => Promise.reject('error2')` is executed. This creates a new, rejected promise, and so a rejection is put on the queue

  - Queue = [promise.then #1 rejected, promise.then #2 rejected]
- The first item in the queue is extracted and processed. It is a rejection, so the `catch` callback `console.log` is executed. This outputs "error1" and creates a new, resolved promise (with undefined value). The queue

  - Queue = [promise.then #2 rejected, promise.then.catch #1 resolved]

... etc

Answer (score 4):

First off, it is kind of pointless to attempt to understand a possible ordering issue between two completely independent promise chains. When programming, you should treat their order as indeterminate (and in fact, as soon as you have real asynchronous operations inside the promise chains which any real promise chain implementations would usually contain, the order will become indeterminate). If the order matters to you between the two chains, then you need to add some specific code to coordinate the actions of the two independent promise chains.

So, the observed order in your snippet is this:

```
error1
error2
continue1
continue3
```

Since you have no async operations in any of your `.then()` or `.catch()` handlers, it will simply alternate between the two promise chains (which is what it appears to be doing when you run your snippet).  Here's how it would basically execute:

1. First `Promise.resolve()` executes which adds to the event queue an event to run its `.then()` handlers.
2. Second `Promise.resolve()` executes which adds to the event queue an event to run its `.then()` handlers.
3. Your sequence of JS is done so control returns back to the event queue.  First `.then()` handler is called which then inserts another event into the event queue to run the `.catch()` handler and returns control back to the event loop.
4. Second `.then()` handler is at the top of the event queue and gets to run
5. And so on...

Keep in mind that per the promise specification each successive `.then()` or `.catch()` handler must be run asynchronously (on the next turn of the event queue).  The promise chain doesn't execute as far as it can in one fell swoop.  It executes the next step, puts the step after that into the queue and then returns control to the event loop which pops the next event off the queue.  This will cause control to rotate between different promise chains that aren't waiting for something else to complete.

But, I repeat, you should not be depending upon this level of execution order and, in more complicated real-world cases with other async operations involved, you could not event attempt to predict an order.  You should assume that these two separate promise chains run in an indeterminate order beyond the synchronous part (each `Promise.resolve()`).  And, then if any specific ordering matters to your code, you must add code to actually synchronize and control the execution order using `Promise.all()` or linking the chains together into one branched chain or one sequence chain or something like that depending upon the needs of the code.

Comment: Actually the order is guaranteed - I agree with the conclusion though (that it should not be relied on)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - Yeah, kind of what I thought (makes sense), but as soon as there are real asynchronous operations in any of the `.then()` or `.catch()` handlers, it's completely unpredictable anyway.  The order is only guaranteed in this non-real-world test.  After all, one wouldn't even have multiple steps in the chain if there weren't actually multiple (unpredictable) asynchronous operations involved.

Comment: Precisely and absolutely.

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure the exact execution order of unrelated promises is specified anywhere, and even if it is, you probably want to introduce some explicit ordering dependency between the two promises if this is important to you.

But here is one possible and likely sequence:

- Step one: Both promises are already resolved
- Step two: Being resolved, both promises run their first `then`. This results in both being rejected.  I would not depend on the order in which these two execute with respect to each-other.
- Step three: Being rejected, both promises run their second `catch/then`. I would not depend on the order in which these two execute with respect to each-other.

You can *probably* depend on these steps going in that order (because it follows the queuing order of how these callbacks were submitted to the scheduler), but even that seems risky.

If you want to have the `continue1` happen before the `error2` you have to arrange code that waits for completion of the former.